# Is there a good C++ key-value data structure where a value is mapped to a range of values?

Tags: c++, data-structures, key-value, intervals

I've been coding with C++ for a few years now and I've been working on a personal project of mine for a few months now. I'll spare you the details, but I've found myself in a situation where it would be very convenient to have some data structure designed in a way that each value would be mapped to a unique, varied-length interval or range of key values.

So, for example, calling a function with any key in the interval [0, 9) would return 17, but a call with a key greater or equal to 9 would return another value, although in my actual case the value would not necessarily be a literal type. Something like this:

```
template <std::totally_ordered T>
struct Interval
{
    T lower;
    T upper;
};


template <std::totally_ordered KeyType, typename ValueType>
class IntervalTable
{
    // Implementation here.

    public:

    ValueType& getValue(const KeyType& key);
};
```

There are a few ways I could imagine this being implemented, with some version of an array or map being the most likely candidates, but I couldn't easily find an already existing structure online, and I was wondering if anyone knew of a well-known structure or solution so I wouldn't spend a lot of time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You can probably build it out of `std::map<K, V>::lower_bound()`.

Comment: Are your ranges allowed to overlap?

Comment: @BenjaminBuch No, the intervals will not overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your intervals in a `std::vector<std::pair<Interval<KeyType>, ValueType>>` and use `std::lower_bound` to find the correct one:

```cpp
template <std::totally_ordered KeyType, typename ValueType>
class IntervalTable {
public:

    ValueType& operator[](const KeyType& key) {
        auto it = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), key,
            [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) { return lhs.first.upper <= rhs; });
        return it->second;
    }

    std::vector<std::pair<Interval<KeyType>, ValueType>> data;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9P5dxfd1P)

Add sanity checks to avoid overlapping intervals and make sure that the `vector` is always sorted.

Comment: This seems straightforward, but do you know if the search time would be linear?

Comment: The complexity is at most log 2(last - first) + O(1) comparisons according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound).

Comment: `std::lower_bound` assumes the container is sorted, and works in logarithmic time

Answer (score 0):

Boost Interval Container Library or libinterval library?
A data structure that could work for your use case is an interval tree since it works by partitioning the number line into intervals and storing those intervals in a binary search tree.

In your case, you could store your key-value pairs as intervals, with each interval being represented by an Interval struct like the one you defined. The lower field of each interval would be the lower bound of the interval (inclusive), and the upper field would be the upper bound of the interval (exclusive).

Comment: Do you think any one of these would be a particularly good fit? While a good search time would be great, it isn't necessary.